# Whole gene sequence analysis to determine source infection

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, dna-sequencing, infection

Is it possible to use whole gene sequence analysis to distinguish between a common source infection and a person-person disease transmission?

Comment: Is this a question out of general curiosity or is it part of a homework or research project?  I ask because while genome sequencing of pathogens can be used to distinguish routes of transmission, it is not usually necessary.  Usually just sequencing specific regions is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for this. A guest lecturer referred to this practice while giving a talk. I cannot understand the process or understand how it would work. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you able to comment any further  please?

Comment: Sure, the idea is pretty straight forward.  Suppose you have a single source of an infection: each new infection should be fairly similar to that original source.  However if the infection transmits person to person, each new copy should be similar to the original copy, so errors will be more likely to accumulate.